# Mutiprocessing doesn't work in python web-scraping

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

I have done with web-scraping using beautifulsoup and successfully save the parsed data into csv files but I want to speed up the process so I use multiprocessing. But there is no difference after I apply multiprocessing in the script. Here is my code

```
rootPath = '....' 
urlp1 = "https://www.proteinatlas.org/"

try:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(rootPath + "cancer_list1_2(1).csv", header=0);
except Exception as e:
    print("File " + f + " doesn't exist")
    print(str(e))
    sys.exit()

cancer_list = df1.as_matrix().tolist()
# [["bcla_gene","beast+cancer"], ...]

URLs = []
for cancer in cancer_list:

    urlp2 = "/pathology/tissue/" + cancer[1]
    f = cancer[0]
    
    try:
        df1 = pd.read_csv(rootPath + f + ".csv", header=0);
    except Exception as e:
        print("File " + f + " doesn't exist")
        print(str(e))
        sys.exit()
    ... # list of urls

def scrape(url,output_path):
    page = urlopen(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    item_text = soup.select('#scatter6001 script')[0].text
    table = soup.find_all('table',{'class':'noborder dark'})
    df1 = pd.read_html(str(table),header = 0)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1[0])
    Number = soup.find('th',text = "Number of samples").find_next_sibling("td").text 


...
#function of scraping



if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(scrape(url,output_path) for url in URLs)
```

Just update the code and the problem now is the CPU utilization can reach 100% only at beginning but soon will drop to 1%. I'm quite confused about that.

Comment: you start one and only one thread, not process and not multi.

Answer (score 0):

Without going to any details in your code: You may benefit from having a look at the [joblib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/joblib) module.

**Pseudocode:**

```
import joblib

if __name__ == "__main__":
      URLs = ["URL1", "URL2", "URL2", ...]
      Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(scrape(url,output_path) for url in URLs)
```

Refactoring your code may be necessary because joblib only works if no code runs outside any `def:` and `if __name__ == "__main__":`-branch.

`n_jobs=-1` will start a number of processes equivalent to the number of cores on your machine. For further details, refer to joblib's [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/).

Using this approach together with selenium/geckodriver, it is possible scrape a pool of 10k URLs in less than an hour depending on your machine (I usually open 40-50 processes on a octacore machine with 64GB ram).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. After modifying the code as you suggestion I can see all the CPUs are used but this only happens at beginning. When I run the program the utilization of CPU is 100% but soon will drop to 1%. Do you know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: please feel free to edit your question so that it contains a reductive example of your current, updated code

Comment: Just update the code, feel free to check it out. Thanks